# How to integrate gservice account to java application?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I want to add gservice account to the java-config file. What are the mandatory fields?
A sample of current config consists

```
properties += [
 bigtableConfig: [
   projected: ,
   instanceId: ,
   tableName: ,
   privateKeyContent:
 ]
]
```

And need to modify this with these details

```
my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The `client_email` and `private_key` are mandatory.

Some of the other fields such as `client_id` and `client_x509_cert_url` improve performance / make validation easier depending on the actual use case.

However, you should include all values. Base64 encode the entire service account JSON key file as some clients expect additional keys.

Note: There are several strategies for managing service accounts. If your application is running on a Google Cloud compute service, review Application Default Credentials (ADC). Including the service account JSON key can be a security risk.